# Unique solution using eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a linear system
$$
A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}
$$ where $$
A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 0 \\ a^2 & 4 & 3a \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}, \quad\mathbf{b}=\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix}, 
$$ Questions: (1) Determine the eigenvalues of matrix $A$ in terms of $a$.

Also, consider the linear system defined by $B\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ :
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}-5 & 1 & 0 \\ a^2 & -3 & 3a \\ 0 & 0 & -5 \end{bmatrix}
$$(2) By using the result, determine the values of $a$ so that a unique solution can be obtained. Hint: First determine the relationship $A$ and $B$ by subtracting the matrices.

So, I know that $A - B=7I_3$ which makes $B = -(7I_3 - A)$. I'm confused why do we have to go to eigenvalues if we can just make an augmented matrix from $B$ to $\mathbf{b}$ then just continue from there? What is the relation with subtracting $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: Remember that a matrix $A$ is invertible, i.e. $Ax=b$ contains a unique solution, when there is no eigenvalue equal to zero

Comment: You could use this: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297419/eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-a-plus-ci-for-some-constant-c)